# Rails3+Devise+Simple_form: Singular resource & simple_form_for errors in path helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

Got 2 questions:

1. How can I get the simple_form_for to work with singular resource :foo_object that's associated to :users (see code excerpts below)? I get NoMethodError: undefined method `foo_objects_path` for `@foo` in the `simple_form_for` line. `foo_object_path` has a valid path but it seems `simple_form_for` is using the plural version. I've google'd & read SO posts regarding singular resource and path issues, but haven't found a solution to this.
2. Do I need to create a nested resource for :foo_object since it's associated to :user? If yes, then will it conflict with Devise's User model?

Routes:

```
devise_for :users  
resource :foo_object
```

Model:

```
:user is the Devise User's model and has_one :foo_object  
:foo_object belongs_to :user
```

View (haml): (update 6/27/13: corrected to = from -)

```
= simple_form_for @foo do |f|
    = f.input :firstname
    = f.input :lastname
    = f.button :submit
```

Hope it's clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [a note](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/cf5bcf7fa85e106640152f717b3af6f9eeba2463) in guides about this. Here's a workaround:

```
= simple_form_for @foo, url: foo_object_path do |f|
    = f.input :firstname
    = f.input :lastname
    = f.button :submit
```

Comment: This solves the NoMethodError in #1. The form does not render now! (Looking into it.) Any answers on the other 2 questions?

Comment: I figured out why the form did not render and updated the answer to reflect it. Otherwise the solution of adding the url is correct.