# has_one relationship without nested_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, has-one

I'm trying to implement a has_one relationship through a basic form and am getting completely stuck.

I seem to have tried huge numbers of combinations of things in controllers and forms but don't seem to be getting anywhere.

I have a phone number for which I use an external service populated by an api.

Eventually I would like to have all the phone numbers of this type set up for this, but right now I'd be happy with getting just one working.

```
parent.rb

has_one :clever_phone
```

And a phone model

```
clever_phone.rb

attr_accessible :number, :parent_id, :prefix, :country_iso
belongs_to :parent
```

Controller

```
clever_phones_controller

def new
@parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id])
@clever_phone = @parent.build_clever_phone


def create

@parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id]
@clever_phone = Parent.create_clever_phone(params[:clever_phone])
```

View
I really don't want to do a nested form from the parent here as I have some complicated code which generates information used in the creation through an api that sits, correctly I think, in the clever_phones_controller

```
@simple_form_for @clever_phone do |f|

= f.input :country_iso, as: :country, :iso_codes => true, priority: ["gb"]
= f.input :prefix

= f.submit
```

Routes

```
 resources :parent do
   resource :clever_phone
 end
```

My issue is that the params for @parent don't seem to be being passed to the create method in the controller and thus I get a 
    'Can't find parent without ID'
error

If I try it as a nested form
I get
    NoMethodError undefined method 'parent_clever_phones_path'
When in fact I've not used that, only parent_clever_phone_path (note the absence of plural).

I'm sure this should be really simple but I've stared at it for hours now and am at the end of my tether...

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Rails 3 or 4?

Comment: Sorry. Using ruby 2.1.2 and rails 3.2.13

Comment: I've loked all over the shop for the has_one thing, and I just can't seem to find a simple 'this is how you do it' which includes the controllers and form views. Every explanation I've seen seems to think that once you have Active Record done then Bob's your uncle yet there seems to be so many little rules you just have to 'know'...

Comment: Writing an answer, but will happily refactor it upon your comments

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there are several issues which you need to contend:

--

**Variable**

The reason why `@parent` params are not being passed is because you've not included them in your form. This is where nesting your forms would come in very handy - passing your `parent` params, and your `clever_phone` params in  a single call

Since you don't want to do this, I would recommend at least populating a `hidden field` with the `parent_id` that the `clever_phone` is associated with:

```
#app/views/clever_phones/new.html.erb
= simple_form_for @clever_phone do |f|

= f.input :parent_id, as: :hidden, value: params[:parent_id]
= f.input :country_iso, as: :country, :iso_codes => true, priority: ["gb"]
= f.input :prefix
= f.submit
```

--

**Route**

Alternatively, you have to make sure you're able to create the correct route for your form (as I think the `@parent = Parent.find params[:parent_id]` is not being called on your `create` method:

```
#app/views/clever_phones/new.html.erb
= simple_form_for [@parent, @clever_phone] do |f|
```

This will give you the ability to point your `create` action to the *nested* version of your route; hence providing the `parent_id` param for you

--

Having written, this I don't think it will address the core of your issue. If you need more information, please write a comment & I'll happily work to create a more appropriate answer!

Comment: I think we're getting there. I tried variations on both of these themes and got different distances with the solutions but never to the end. 
I think there might be something connected to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336533/rails3devisesimple-form-singular-resource-simple-form-for-errors-in-path-he

Comment: Hmm!! Are you using `Devise`? Do you have any specific details you could relay back to me about the error / log?

Comment: Ok. Using a url: parameter from that answer above I think I'm getting all the way there. except I then get 
    ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find PlivoNumber without an ID:

Comment: `url: parameter` - where are you setting `parameter`?

Comment: Okay! The problem you have here is that your route will only be setting the `@parent` params I think. You should try `=simple_form_for [@parent, @plivo_number]`

Answer (score 1):

Right: Worth putting in the solution that finally worked. 
Thanks to Rich Peck for getting me halfway there...
model

```
parent.rb
  has_one :clever_phone

clever_phone.rb
  belongs_to :parent
```

view

```
simple_form_for @clever_phone, url: parent_clever_phone_path(@parent) do |f|

-----
f.input :parent_id, :value: @parent.id
-----
```

routes

```
 resources :parent do
   resource :clever_phone
```

controller

```
def new 
....
@parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id])
@clever_phone = @parent.build_clever_phone

def create
@parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id]
@clever_phone = CleverPhone.new(params[:clever_phone]
```

Unless you do build_clever_phone the parent_id won't populate. I couldn't get @parent.create_clever_phone to work, but this seemed to do the trick...

Hope that saves somebody a days work...